# Updating in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm trying to figure out how to update a chart.js chart. Google's returned with a lot of answers and I think some are outdated because I can't seem to get any of the solutions to work. The documentation page says just use `chartname.update()` but it doesn't seem to work for me. I already checked console to make sure the chart object was updating. For some reason the chart itself on the page just isn't changing.

```
let chartContainer = document.getElementById('charts');
let overview = {
    create: function () {
        let chartCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        chartCanvas.id = 'overviewChart';
        chartCanvas.appendChild(document.createTextNode('test'));
        chartContainer.appendChild(chartCanvas);
        let overviewChart = document.getElementById('overviewChart').getContext('2d');
        renderChart = new Chart(overviewChart, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels:subjectList,
                datasets: [{
                    barThickness: 'flex',
                    label: 'Completed Credits',
                    data: []
                }]
            },
            options: {

            }
        })
    },
    reload: function() {
        console.log('reloaded overview chart');
        renderChart.data.datasets.data = [];
        for (subject in classes) {
            console.log('adding: ' + classes[subject].count)
            renderChart.data.datasets.data.push(classes[subject].count);
        }
        renderChart.update();
    }
}

function reloadCharts() {
    overview.reload();
}

overview.create();
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working code example- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  (Add snippet). https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems in your `reload` function where you access `renderChart.data.datasets`.
Please note that `renderChart.data.datasets` is an array. Therefore, you need to make the following changes:

```
reload: function() {
    // renderChart.data.datasets.data = []; // old
    renderChart.data.datasets[0].data = []; // new
    for (subject in classes) {
        console.log('adding: ' + classes[subject].count)
        // renderChart.data.datasets.data.push(classes[subject].count); // old
        renderChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(classes[subject].count); // new
    }
    renderChart.update();
}
```